# ADO Rest API blocked by CORS policy when testing locally

Tags: cors, azure-devops-rest-api

So I'm trying to create a single page app which we use as a dashboard for our dev ops statuses.  We already have something in place, but I want to extend it's functionality, requiring calls to the ADO rest api.

I'm following this example: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/blob/master/JavascriptWebAppSample/README.md

So far I've managed to get the app running, logging in, requesting access, and calling the ADO API.  When it calls it however, I get the error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://dev.azure.com/{my_org}/_apis/projects?api-version=4.0' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The request I'm making has a bearer token set to it, according to this MS docs page I think the server should be allowing cross origin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/how-to/call-rest-api?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors

I've seen a few examples of how to fix this online, but struggling to get something working.  I'm also not sure why the sample doesn't work as is.

I'm running the site locally and using chrome v115.0.5790.170